# How to show a circle with given radius around a bing maps pushpin on hover?

Tags: html, asp.net, maps, bing-maps, bing

I want to be able to type in a number for a radius. Then whenever I hover over any given pushpin on the map it will show a circle with that radius.

Then if I would be able to grab a list of pushpins within that radius when you hover over the pushpin that would be awesome too.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can find a module for Bing Maps V7 that adds support for circles here: https://bingmapsv7modules.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Circle%20Module